# Are there events for connect.static?

Tags: events, node.js, static, connect, fileserver

I need to react to the start and end of file-serves from a

nodejs + connect + connect.static() + connect.staticCache() environment.

i can't find any documentation on it :(

Does connect.static (+ static.cache!!) provide any events ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for `connect`, it seems that it issues a `static` event on the request, passing the stream. So something like the below should work:

```
var connect = require("connect")
  , app = connect.createServer();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.on("static", function(stream) {
    console.log("serving " + req.url);
    stream.on("end", function() {
      console.log("served " + req.url);
    });
  });
  next();
});
app.use(connect.static(__dirname));

app.listen(3000);
```